# How to make LastWriteTime return culture sensitive date string

Tags: date, powershell, output

I have this:

```
$LogfileInfo = Get-Item C:\windows
$LogfileInfo.LastWriteTime
"Explaining Text: " + $LogfileInfo.LastWriteTime
```

Line 2 output is:

```
21. maj 2015 13:44:45
```

Line 3 output is:

```
Explaining Text: 05/21/2015 13:44:45
```

It changes the output, even though it is the same variable!?

How can I get the line 2 output (naming the month, and not reversing the day/month), but with text in front, like in line 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default output for System.DateTime is the DateTime:

```powershell
"Explaining Text: " + $LogfileInfo.LastWriteTime.DateTime
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. Output is now: "Explaining Text: 21. maj 2015 13:44:45"

Answer (score 1):

At some point the `DateTime` value is converted to a string. Depending when this is done different settings of current culture and default formatting can apply.

In

> ```
> $LogfileInfo.LastWriteTime
> ```

the conversion to string is done within PSH's `out-default` which is applied to any pipeline without another `out-…` cmdlet at its end. This will make use of default formatting definitions (`.format.ps1xml` files) for `System.DateTime`.

But in

> ```
> "Explaining Text: " + $LogfileInfo.LastWriteTime
> ```

the conversion happens when the string is made.

Try replacing the first with

```
$LogfileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString()
```

and you should get the same format as the first.

Comment: Thanks. Also works. Doesn't keep the naming of the month, but makes sure the day/month is not switched. Output is now: "Explaining Text: 21-05-2015 13:44:45"

Comment: @Lisbjerg You probably need to be explicit about the format you want.See [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).